# Unable to put 0px margin

Tags: html, css

How to remove extra margin from the div tag.

I have already added `margin` and `padding` to `0px`. Does positioning also matters in margin? Even if I want to give margin in this div, so in which unit should I give like in vw or percentage? Please help to resolve this issue

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #menubar {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #menubar ol li {
      color: white;
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0.5em 0.3em;
      background-color: #007ac2;
      padding-top: 1em;
      padding-right: 45px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menubar">
    <ol>
      <li id="abouthover"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <div class="arrow-up">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="innovationhover"><a href="#">INNOVATION</a>
        <div class="arrow-up2"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="capabilitieshover"><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a>
        <div class="arrow-up3"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="careerhover"><a href="#">CAREER</a>
        <div class="arrow-up4">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="investorhover"><a href="#">INVESTOR RELATIONS</a>
        <div class="arrow-up5"></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: It isn't div extra margin. It is ol margins

Comment: Am I the only one who's not understanding about what he really want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of browser defaults. Add the following to your stylesheet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #menubar {
      margin: 0;
    }
   #menubar a{
      text-decoration:none;
      color: white;
    }
   #menubar ol {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
   }
    #menubar ol li {
      color: white;
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0.5em 0.3em;
      background-color: #007ac2;
      padding-top: 1em;
      padding-right: 45px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menubar">
    <ol>
      <li id="abouthover"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <div class="arrow-up">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="innovationhover"><a href="#">INNOVATION</a>
        <div class="arrow-up2"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="capabilitieshover"><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a>
        <div class="arrow-up3"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="careerhover"><a href="#">CAREER</a>
        <div class="arrow-up4">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="investorhover"><a href="#">INVESTOR RELATIONS</a>
        <div class="arrow-up5"></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Ankit_Aryan Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the margin and padding of the HTML doc, and * (everything). See snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* FROM HERE */
    
    *,
    html {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    /* TO HERE */
    
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #menubar {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #menubar ol li {
      color: white;
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0.5em 0.3em;
      background-color: #007ac2;
      padding-top: 1em;
      padding-right: 45px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menubar">
    <ol>
      <li id="abouthover"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <div class="arrow-up">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="innovationhover"><a href="#">INNOVATION</a>
        <div class="arrow-up2"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="capabilitieshover"><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a>
        <div class="arrow-up3"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="careerhover"><a href="#">CAREER</a>
        <div class="arrow-up4">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="investorhover"><a href="#">INVESTOR RELATIONS</a>
        <div class="arrow-up5"></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.This is all that I wanted Can you suggest any good resource for css to learn?

Comment: @ANKITARYAN glad this helped out. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) is a nice resource to learn and help out with CSS. Also may I ask you to upvote, and mark the answer as accepted, so that future visitors find a solution to their problem faster? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Try This:***

```
ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#menubar {
  margin: 0;
}

#menubar ol li {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0.3em;
  background-color: #007ac2;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <ol>
    <li id="abouthover"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
      <div class="arrow-up">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="innovationhover"><a href="#">INNOVATION</a>
      <div class="arrow-up2"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="capabilitieshover"><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a>
      <div class="arrow-up3"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="careerhover"><a href="#">CAREER</a>
      <div class="arrow-up4">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="investorhover"><a href="#">INVESTOR RELATIONS</a>
      <div class="arrow-up5"></div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```